# VHDL Error "expecting begin"

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity data_choose is
port(
A :in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
B: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
clk : in std_logic);
end entity data_choose;

architecture select_data of data_choose is


variable count : integer range 0 to 7;


count :=0;

begin


if (rising_edge(clk)) then 
count := count + 1 ;
if((count > 1)) then
    if((count rem 2)=0) then 
        B <= A;
    end if;
end if;
end if;
end architecture select_data ;
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code.
Near the count initialisation statement there is a compilation error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this code.

```
variable count : integer range 0 to 7;
```

I suggest you make this a `signal`, not a `variable`. I would also suggest avoiding variables until you have a solid understanding of how they differ from signals. You would normally declare a variable inside a process, for use exclusively by that process. Something that needs to be accessed by more than one process would normally use a signal declared in the architecture (where you currently have your variable declaration).

```
count :=0;
```

You have this assignment in the architecture's declarative region, between the `architecture ... is` and `begin`. If you need to initialise the counter, you can use:

```
signal count : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
```

Onto the next issue, your line `if (rising_edge(clk)) then` is attempting to describe synchronous logic. This should take place inside a process, so you would have:

```
process (clk)
begin
  if (rising_edge(clk)) then 
    ...
  end if;
end process;
```

The last error is then that since your `count` is now a signal, you should assign to it using `<=`, not `:=`, giving `count <= count + 1 ;`

With these changes made, your code compiles.

Comment: What about count incremented beyond 7 which would produce a bound constraint error?

Comment: @user1155120 If the asker came back with that problem, I would suggest that they create a new question.